# Calculating the y axis wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently stuck in a tricky situation. I want to plot a data frame using `ggplot2` and the `ggplotly()` function to make it interactive. I created the data frame myself. But now, when I'm trying to plot the data frame, R is putting the values on the y axis in the wrong order.

The code I'm using:

**1. The data frame**:

```
USA_G7v2 <- data.frame(USAv2 = c("541945", "562886", "609085", "669576", "784362", "850051", "877983", "894973", "1014603", "1025091", "1017020", "1049943", "1138765", "1149043", "1241665", "1243148", "1350002", "1442058", "1309820", "1521441"), Jahr =c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"))
```

**2. The code to plot:**

```
v <- USA_G7v2%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Jahr, y=USAv2, group=1))+
  geom_area(alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("Investitionen (Mio $")+
  theme_ipsum()
```

**3. The interactive part:**

```
ggplotly(v)
```

And the result looks like this:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yiug.png)

I really dont know what I'm doing wrong and would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing characters, e.g. `"123"` to the dataframe instead of numbers (`123`).

The issue will be resolved if you convert the data to numeric format. Here is one way to do it

```r
v <- USA_G7v2 %>%
  mutate(Jahr = as.numeric(Jahr),
         USAv2 = as.numeric(USAv2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Jahr, y=USAv2, group=1))+
  geom_area(alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("Investitionen (Mio $")+
  theme_ipsum()
```